# JAVA how to find the target file path that a symbolic link points to?

Tags: java, symlink, rhel

I'm trying to find a way in Java to figure out the file path that a symbolic link is pointing to.
We have a system that monitors a symbolic link folder, does some stuff based on the file name, deletes that symbolic link file.
What I need to do is figure out where each symbolic link file is pointing to so I can delete that file as well when the symbolic link.
This is using Java on a RHEL system.

Any guidance to API topics would be greatly appreciated. I'm hitting a wall on my searches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-

> Path toRealPath(LinkOption... options)
>            throws IOException Returns the real path of an existing file. The precise definition of this method is implementation dependent but
>   in general it derives from this path, an absolute path that locates
>   the same file as this path, but with name elements that represent the
>   actual name of the directories and the file. For example, where
>   filename comparisons on a file system are case insensitive then the
>   name elements represent the names in their actual case. Additionally,
>   the resulting path has redundant name elements removed.
>
> If this path is relative then its absolute path is first obtained, as
>   if by invoking the toAbsolutePath method.
>
> The options array may be used to indicate how symbolic links are
>   handled. By default, symbolic links are resolved to their final
>   target. If the option NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then this method does
>   not resolve symbolic links. Some implementations allow special names
>   such as ".." to refer to the parent directory. When deriving the real
>   path, and a ".." (or equivalent) is preceded by a non-".." name then
>   an implementation will typically cause both names to be removed. When
>   not resolving symbolic links and the preceding name is a symbolic link
>   then the names are only removed if it guaranteed that the resulting
>   path will locate the same file as this path.
>
> Parameters: options - options indicating how symbolic links are
>   handled Returns: an absolute path represent the real path of the file
>   located by this object Throws: IOException - if the file does not
>   exist or an I/O error occurs SecurityException - In the case of the
>   default provider, and a security manager is installed, its checkRead
>   method is invoked to check read access to the file, and where this
>   path is not absolute, its checkPropertyAccess method is invoked to
>   check access to the system property user.dir

Use the toRealPath() method from nio. The NO_FOLLOW_LINKS LinkOption does the opposite of what you are trying to do, so don't use it.

```
Path realPath = aFile.toPath().toRealPath()

Path realPath = aPath().toRealPath()
```

One gotcha with this, is that, unlike `toAbsolutePath`, `toRealPath` throws an `IOException` since it actually has to interact with the file system to find the real path.

Comment: Great details and link to the API, additional note that the exception SecurityException can also be thrown. This was exactly the information that I needed. Thanks for your help @Novaterata

Comment: Right, but IOException is checked so you'll either have to modify your interface or use a try/catch

Answer (score 10):

`java.nio.file.Files.readSymbolicLink` might be what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the import path.

Comment: beware that it will return a relative path, say `/usr/local/link -> ./file` for `/usr/local/file`. Then Files.readSymbolicLink returns `file` and `Paths.get("/usr/local/files").equals( Files.readSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/usr/local/link")))` is false. In this case I used `Files.isSameFile(file, link)`. And to get the absolute path of the target file of a link, `link.toRealPath()`